# Animate transitions for UI's sortable list

Tags: jquery, animation, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable, transition

I am working with an **`jQueryUI` sortable list**, and want to animate the transitions when `li`s are moved around as I drag an element up or down. As **Apple** have done it in their *iPod app* when rearranging a playlist's songs.

Is this possible? I've searched for hours, but cannot find anything useful.

Comment: I've made a related feature request [here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/10579) to ease this task.

Answer (score 2):

I've put the code that user1754406 found on [github](https://gist.github.com/801570) into jsfiddle, it was just what I was looking for:

[http://jsfiddle.net/samjones00/AbpJF/](http://jsfiddle.net/samjones00/AbpJF/3/)

> `Too much code to paste, please see the code on jsfiddle`

Answer (score 1):

The revert option is what you want I think.

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-revert

The jQuery documentation is very well written and it looks like they are in the process of making it even better. Their methods are also very robust and usually have at the very least some callback event you can tap into to perform things. Make sure you always look there first!

Oh in case you need it, your code adds options like this:

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
     revert:300,
     //other options you need go here, comma separated
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it isn't revert I'm looking for though. You know, when dragging an element, the elements that you are not dragging, moves up and down depending on where you are dragging your element to. But - they just pop around - I want them to animate. So they move smoothly around..

Comment: Ahh hmm, well that would be pretty tricky as the plugin is changing the position of the placeholder in the list as you drag something over within a certain amount of pixels. I'm not sure there is any way of doing that with sortable as it would require a lot of extra DOM manipulation.

Comment: On the event that moves the spot placeholder up in the list tree, you'd have to first grab it's position, then animate the top or bottom list element into it's current position before moving the placeholder.

Comment: I've found something that actually works, but can't get it to work in my code.. :S https://gist.github.com/801570

Comment: It looks like he's using '.marker' as his placeholder, so you need to make sure to copy lines 6-20 into your code or CSS file. Instead of animating the positions, he's setting the top border to the imposter size and animating that with a CSS transition. I'm guessing it's not working because you don't have the marker styles in your code