# jQuery UI Sortable - Sliding Divs on X Axis

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've been searching for a solution to this and haven't had any luck.

I have a container with a bunch of divs in it and made them sortable on the X-axis. What I am hoping to find is something that will "slide" or "ease" the other divs around as the user drags across instead of "popping" them into place.

Any help would be appreciated, cheers!

http://jsfiddle.net/V43Qd/1/

**CODE**

```
 $( "#dragBubbleContainer" ).sortable({ 
        tolerance: "pointer",
        axis: "x",
        opacity: 0.5,
     });

 $( "#dragBubbleContainer" ).disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to add a sliding animation to the sortable list by hiding/showing the placeholder.

Found the answer here: [jQuery Sortable with animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060357/jquery-sortable-with-animation)

**DEMO**
http://jsfiddle.net/V43Qd/3/

```
    $( "#dragBubbleContainer" ).sortable({ 
        tolerance: "pointer",
        axis: "x",
        opacity: 0.5,
        start: function(e, ui){
            $(ui.placeholder).hide(300);
        },
        change: function (e,ui){
            $(ui.placeholder).hide().show(300);
        }
     });
    $( "#dragBubbleContainer" ).disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS transitions and jQuery easing are two possible approaches. See [Animating jQueryUI Sortable using CSS3 transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261889/animating-jqueryui-sortable-using-css3-transitions/13283200#13283200).

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060357/jquery-sortable-with-animation